# Different results between glfw offscreen and window rendering with large images

Tags: python, opengl, glfw, texture-mapping, texture2d

I am having different results using glfw window and offscreen rendering. I want to apply texture mapping using this [texture_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkUzd.png) on a mesh. The image dimension is 3500 x 1752.

My code for rendering and displaying the rendered image on a pop-up glfw window is as follows:

```
t_obj = "mesh.obj"
tex_file_path = "texture.png"

tex_im = cv2.imread(tex_file_path)
h, w = tex_im.shape[:2]
vertices, tex_coords, indices = load_obj_file(t_obj, dimension=3)
colors = np.ones((len(vertices), 3), dtype=np.float)

vertices = np.hstack((vertices, colors, tex_coords))
vertices = np.array(vertices, dtype=np.float32)

# a vertex shader consists of x, y, z and w.
vertex_src = """
# version 330
layout(location = 0) in vec3 a_position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 a_color;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 a_texture;
uniform mat4 rotation;
out vec3 v_color;
out vec2 v_texture;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = rotation * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
    v_color = a_color;
    v_texture = a_texture;

    //v_texture = 1 - a_texture;                      // Flips the texture vertically and horizontally
    //v_texture = vec2(a_texture.s, 1 - a_texture.t); // Flips the texture vertically
}
"""

# fragment shader consists of R, G, B and A.
fragment_src = """
# version 330
in vec3 v_color;
in vec2 v_texture;
out vec4 out_color;
uniform sampler2D s_texture;
void main()
{
    out_color = texture(s_texture, v_texture) * vec4(v_color, 1.0f);
}
"""


# glfw callback functions
def window_resize(window, width, height):
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height)


# initializing glfw library
if not glfw.init():
    raise Exception("glfw can not be initialized!")

# creating the window
# glfw.window_hint(glfw.VISIBLE, glfw.FALSE)
window = glfw.create_window(w, h, "My OpenGL window", None, None)

# check if window was created
if not window:
    glfw.terminate()
    raise Exception("glfw window can not be created!")

# set window's position
glfw.set_window_pos(window, w, h)

# set the callback function for window resize
glfw.set_window_size_callback(window, window_resize)

# make the context current
glfw.make_context_current(window)

shader = compileProgram(compileShader(vertex_src, GL_VERTEX_SHADER),
                        compileShader(fragment_src, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER))

# Step2: Create and bind VBO objects to transfer data
VBO = glGenBuffers(1)  # request a buffer slot from GPU.
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO)  # make this buffer the default one.
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.nbytes, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW)  # upload CPU data to GPU buffer.

# Step3: Create and bind EBO object to transfer data
EBO = glGenBuffers(1)
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO)
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.nbytes, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
# Step4: Specify the resolution method and enable vertex attributes
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, vertices.itemsize * 8, ctypes.c_void_p(0))
# Vertex color attributes
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, vertices.itemsize * 8, ctypes.c_void_p(12))
# Vertex texture attributes
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2)
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, vertices.itemsize * 8, ctypes.c_void_p(24))

texture = glGenTextures(1)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture)

# Set the texture wrapping parameters
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT)
# Set texture filtering parameters
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)

# load image
image = Image.open(tex_file_path)
image = image.transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM)
img_data = image.convert("RGBA").tobytes()
# Attach a texture image to the texture buffer.
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, image.width, image.height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img_data)

glUseProgram(shader)
glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1)
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glEnable(GL_BLEND)
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)

model = pyrr.matrix44.create_from_translation(pyrr.Vector3([0.0, 0.0, 0]))
rotation_loc = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "rotation")

# the main application loop
while not glfw.window_should_close(window):
    glfw.poll_events()
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    glUniformMatrix4fv(rotation_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, model)
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, len(indices), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, None)

    glfw.swap_buffers(window)

# save_image
data = glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)
pil_image = Image.frombytes("RGBA", (w, h), data)
pil_image = ImageOps.flip(pil_image)
pil_image.save('output.png')
glfw.terminate()
```

The result is [with_popup_window_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1alA.png).

However, the output image saved to disk is resized to a smaller image and then padded so that the final width and height are the same as those of the texture image. Here is the [saved_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzidg.png).

However, if I modify the code so that it does off-screen rendering and does not display the glfw window, the output image is cropped. Here is the modified code:

```
t_obj = "obj_time_0.5.obj"
tex_file_path = "s.png"

tex_im = cv2.imread(tex_file_path)
h, w = tex_im.shape[:2]
vertices, tex_coords, indices = load_obj_file(t_obj, dimension=3)
colors = np.ones((len(vertices), 3), dtype=np.float)

vertices = np.hstack((vertices, colors, tex_coords))
vertices = np.array(vertices, dtype=np.float32)

# a vertex shader consists of x, y, z and w.
vertex_src = """
# version 330
layout(location = 0) in vec3 a_position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 a_color;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 a_texture;
uniform mat4 rotation;
out vec3 v_color;
out vec2 v_texture;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = rotation * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
    v_color = a_color;
    v_texture = a_texture;

    //v_texture = 1 - a_texture;                      // Flips the texture vertically and horizontally
    //v_texture = vec2(a_texture.s, 1 - a_texture.t); // Flips the texture vertically
}
"""

# fragment shader consists of R, G, B and A.
fragment_src = """
# version 330
in vec3 v_color;
in vec2 v_texture;
out vec4 out_color;
uniform sampler2D s_texture;
void main()
{
    out_color = texture(s_texture, v_texture) * vec4(v_color, 1.0f);
}
"""


# glfw callback functions
def window_resize(window, width, height):
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height)


# initializing glfw library
if not glfw.init():
    raise Exception("glfw can not be initialized!")

# creating the window
glfw.window_hint(glfw.VISIBLE, glfw.FALSE)
window = glfw.create_window(w, h, "My OpenGL window", None, None)

# check if window was created
if not window:
    glfw.terminate()
    raise Exception("glfw window can not be created!")

# set window's position
glfw.set_window_pos(window, w, h)

# set the callback function for window resize
glfw.set_window_size_callback(window, window_resize)

# make the context current
glfw.make_context_current(window)

shader = compileProgram(compileShader(vertex_src, GL_VERTEX_SHADER),
                        compileShader(fragment_src, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER))

# Step2: Create and bind VBO objects to transfer data
VBO = glGenBuffers(1)  # request a buffer slot from GPU.
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO)  # make this buffer the default one.
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.nbytes, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW)  # upload CPU data to GPU buffer.

# Step3: Create and bind EBO object to transfer data
EBO = glGenBuffers(1)
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO)
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.nbytes, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
# Step4: Specify the resolution method and enable vertex attributes
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, vertices.itemsize * 8, ctypes.c_void_p(0))
# Vertex color attributes
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, vertices.itemsize * 8, ctypes.c_void_p(12))
# Vertex texture attributes
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2)
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, vertices.itemsize * 8, ctypes.c_void_p(24))

texture = glGenTextures(1)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture)

# Set the texture wrapping parameters
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT)
# Set texture filtering parameters
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)

# load image
image = Image.open(tex_file_path)
image = image.transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM)
img_data = image.convert("RGBA").tobytes()
# Attach a texture image to the texture buffer.
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, image.width, image.height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img_data)

glUseProgram(shader)
glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1)
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glEnable(GL_BLEND)
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)

model = pyrr.matrix44.create_from_translation(pyrr.Vector3([0.0, 0.0, 0]))
rotation_loc = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "rotation")

# the main application loop
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

glUniformMatrix4fv(rotation_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, model)
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, len(indices), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, None)

# save_image
data = glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)
pil_image = Image.frombytes("RGBA", (w, h), data)
pil_image = ImageOps.flip(pil_image)
pil_image.save('output.png')
glfw.destroy_window(window)
glfw.terminate()
```

The saved result for this off-screen rendering is [offscreen_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxVH1.png). It is cropped and padded so the resulting image dimension does not change.

I am wondering what causes these resizing and cropping problems. This only happens when the output dimension is big. I tried passing in smaller dimension (< 1000 x 1000) to `glReadPixels()` and the output images are fine (no resizing or cropping). I read somewhere that one can try using the `frameBufferObject` (FBO) for offscreen rendering instead of using `glfw` but since I do not know how to use FBO, the program crashes when I copying the FBO code from someone else's.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that it is allowed to call `glReadPixels` after `window_should_close` returns false? Imho, capturing the content of a invisible window is undefined behavior. If you want to do off-screen rendering, I suggest to render to FBO and read that back.

Comment: Is `image.width`, `image.height` equal to `width`, `height`?

Comment: @Rabbid76 yes, `image.width` is equal to `width` and same with `height`.

Comment: You're passing in "smaller dimension" to glReadPixles(), but to me you should always pass the amount specified by glViewPort(). Maybe you are already, it's not immediately obvious to me if you are.